# Citrus Test Framework Message Store not Saving Messages

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I am grabbing messages off of an AMQ broker and needing to validate plain text payloads. It seems citrus is very limited with plain text validation, and the validation matchers don't get me where I need to be so I need to deal with it using java code.

Code is done using basic java objects to set up messages being sent and received. When

```
    sendMessageToAMQ(message);

    receivePlainTextMessage(message)
            .selector(message.getHeaderName()+"='"+message.getHeaderValue()+"'")
            .name("sampleName");

    context.getMessageStore().getMessage("sampleName").getPayload();
```

Context is passed in text level as a Citrus Resource. The above line of code (last line) throws a null pointer because the message isn't showing as stored aka message store size = 0. All while echo("citrus:message(sampleName.payload())") prints the payload just fine.

I've even tried variable("msg", "citrus:message(sampleName.payload())") but that returns an error saying cannot find message with name.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The key is: you should use the next method for that .messageName() instead of .name()

Then the message data will be saved into Citrus context

Comment: after viewing several examples and one from the founder himself, Christoph Deppisch, that doesn't seem to be the case. Christoph does it here, (but with TestRunner not TestDesigner like myself): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596054/how-do-i-access-a-citrus-http-receive-message-body-in-java

Comment: also possible related bug causing this or vice versa https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus/issues/718